# push element from one array to another on button click in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I am trying to use the method .contact() to push on element in my old_array to my new_array.
I have one button on each element in the array like this:

´´´

```
<li key={i}>
   {{character.name} + "is" + {character.age} + "years old"}
   <button onClick={this.addToNewArray}>Fav</button>
</li>
```

´´´

so as you can see each element got a seperate id. Now i want to click the button to push that element to a new array . (i get data from API that i .map() into my old_array) My function looks like this:

´´´

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            old_arary: [],
            new_array: []
        }
    }
addToNewArray = () => {
        let new_array = this.state.new_array.contact(this.state.old_array);
        this.setState({ new_array: new_array})

}
```

´´´

This is where i want my output:

´´´

```
<li>
   {this.state.new_array}
</li>
```

´´´

Comment: You are directly mutating the state which is not recommended when you are concating old_array and new_array.
Instead you should be using setState method.

Comment: Now it seems to work BUT i get a huge error: https://gyazo.com/bb68e6fc3837f4ccc2e979305e48e379, it has something to do with the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First :**

in your question , you are using `contact()` everywhere, and I think there is no such function for array in JS :) , that should be `concat()`

**Second :**

You can use ES6 for lower code, something like this:

```
let new_array = [...this.state.new_array , ...this.state.old_array];
this.setState({ new_array });
```

**Third :**

Change this

```
<li>
   {this.state.new_array}
</li>
```

To :

```
{
    this.state.new_array.map((obj,index) => (
        <li key={index}>
            {obj.name}
        </li>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Now it seems to work BUT i get a huge error: https://gyazo.com/bb68e6fc3837f4ccc2e979305e48e379, it has something to do with the api?

Comment: I think you are not getting array, it might be object, try this `let new_array = [...this.state.new_array , this.state.old_array];` if it works then its object and not array

Comment: Yes, it is objects im getting, i tried to change the output to {this.state.new_array.toString()} and i got [object Object],[object Object],... on my screen

Comment: @gospecomid12, that is array my friend, it would be great if you can create a demo and share link, have to debug, this way it won't be possible.

Comment: i actually made it work! i had to iterate over the array using map for it to display correctly.

Comment: @gospecomid12, I already added that in answer as third step, before 20 mins, Glad that you tried your self. Please accept the answer also